# Get the value of one selection field

Tags: odoo

How I affect the value of a field section to a field char.

```
return { value{'field_char' : field_selection.value !!!}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Override create and write method for that,

```
def create(self, cr, uid, vals, context={}):
    if not vals.get('field_selection',False):
        vals.update('field_char') = vals.get('field_selection','')

    return super(class_name,self).create(cr, uid, vals, context=context)

def write(self, cr, uid, ids, vals, context={}):
    if not vals.get('field_selection',False):
        vals.update('field_char') = vals.get('field_selection','')

    return super(class_name,self).write(cr, uid, ids, vals, context=context)
```

Comment: When you want to store selection field value to char field ?

Comment: field1: fields.selection([('a','A')], 'Field1'), field2: fields.char('Field2'), i want to copy the name of an item in the char field ('A') but not the value ('a') return { value{'field2' : field1.!!!}}

Comment: Ohh! men I am asking the event trigger point when you want to copy that value ? on save time ? on update time ? because the way to access that field is different as per event.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to affect it as in onchange event, you just set a parameter to your function with the value you whant of the selection:

```
<field name="field_selection" onchange="do_change(field_selection)" />
```

and then, in your function get the parameter, and affect it to your *field_char*:

```
def do_change(self, cr, uid, ids, selection_val, context=None):
    return { 
         value{
              'field_char' : selection_val
              }
         }
```

Comment: field1: fields.selection([('a','A')], 'Field1'),
field2: fields.char('Field2'),

i want to copy the name of an item in the char field ('A') but not the value ('a')

return { value{'field2' : field1.!!!}}

Answer (score 0):

related to 
field1: fields.selection([('a','A')], 'Field1'), 
field2: fields.char('Field2'),

just try to

fields2 = fields['a']

only pass key it's return value of key